# What is the limit of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{b_i}$ for the decreasing sequence of positive integers $b_n=\frac{x+2^n-1}{2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $x$
be a positive integer,
let $b_k=\dfrac{x+2^k-1}{2^k}$,
and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$
be as large as possible such that $b_n$
is a positive integer.
Consider the sequence $(b_k)_{k=1}^n$.
For example,
taking $x=17$, we retrieve the sequence $(9,5,3,2)$.
Now consider the sum $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{b_k}$.
How does this behave as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Hi Martin, you are right. I put more precision on the question/case: The sequence stops at its lowest integer. In the given case (x=17) for example a $b_5,b_6,\ldots$ does not exist. Hope this helps and it may be much more easier to show that the series is convergent/limited.

Comment: I should ask: How we can show/argue that the sum/series is definitely limited. What is its limit? When playing with the product $(1+\frac{1}{b_1})(1+\frac{1}{b_2})\ldots$ I see it always stays below 4.

Comment: When the sum $(1/b_i)$ is limited, then the product $(1+1/b_i)$ should be limited as well. Thats why I hope it is possible to show the limit of that sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we factor $x-1=2^k y$ where $y$ is odd, then $b_n = 2^{k-n} y + 1$ for all $n$, and thus $b_k$ is the last integral element of the sequence. The sum in question is then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac1{b_i} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac1{2^{k-i} y + 1} < \sum_{i=1}^k \frac1{2^{k-i} y} = \frac1y\bigg( 2-\frac1{2^{k-1}} \bigg) < 2.
$$
The actual best upper bound, when taking $x=2^k+1$ for larger and larger $k$, is approximately $1.2644997803484442092$.

Comment: Thanks for that great explanation! Can we derive from that finding the limit of the product $\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{b_i})$? Based on the fact that the sum is lower than 2, does the product therefore stays below 4?

Comment: Just checked with K. Knopp "Theorie und Anwendung der unendlichen Reihen": The upper bound of the product seems to be $e^{\sum\ldots}=e^{1.2644...}$